# Why php timestamp behave like this? 03/November/1985

Tags: php, timezone, unix-timestamp, mktime

I was trying to make my own php `mktime();` using my default timezone *(America/Sao_Paulo)*.
It was working ok, but I noticed that some timestamps had one hour more than it should be.
So I tracked down and find out this date where the script starts to miss: 03/November/1985
I ran some tests and for some weird reason (that's what I'm trying to understand), this day have only 23 hours!
Check it:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

//shows 23
echo (mktime(0,0,0,11,03,1985)- mktime(0,0,0,11,02,1985))/3600; 

//any other date, shows 24
echo '<br/>'.(mktime(0,0,0,11,3,2000)-mktime(0,0,0,11,2,2000))/3600; 

?>
```

Notice that it doesn't occurs with timezone UTC.
It's a possible bug?

PS: Sorry for english mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You happened to pick the date that represents the start of daylight savings in Brazil for 1985.  See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TimePrecision-HOWTO/tz.html.

So, because of the time change on that specific date, the difference between midnight on the two days is only 23 hours.

Comment: Thank you! I enjoyed the link.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a day light savings time issue. Probably only has 23 hours because DST pushes the clock ahead, skipping 1 hour.

There's an extra argument to [mktime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) called `is_dst`. Try setting it to 0 or 1 and see if that fixes your problem, although the output you're getting might very well be correct.

Comment: Note  `is_dst` parameter has been removed in PHP 7.